# JavaScript stops working for all Google Sheets and Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My **Google Docs** and **Sheets** were working fine yesterday. Today, the same file (no changes made) does not run my JavaScript. In fact, any new Doc/Sheet files I create will **no longer run JavaScript**. It appears that Google itself is blocking JavaScript on my Google account, but I am not sure. There is no error message, no log. I thought it was a device issue, because it started working again on my new devices but, eventually, all my devices have stopped working. Note: My devices have different operating systems, different browsers, but all eventually experience this issue. I tried reinstalling browsers, new Windows installs. Note: even simple JavaScript alert popups will no longer work from my Google files. General web browsing (outside of Google Workspace development) is running good. I am so confused!

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript like client side? or actual Google Apps Script? Have you tried using another account? Can you show screenshots on your issue?

Comment: Hi. I am referring to the client-side JavaScript that gets produced by my Google Apps Script applications. I tried another Google account and it works ok there. It also works ok from my Apple device. It does not work from ANY Windows devices, regardless of version. Here is a screenshot of the JavaScript that does not work (simply a popup alert from a HTML button): [frmTest.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h8hBWUH24-3sUJXwOODXFuMha8VeETqm/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

I am going to close this question. I have discovered that google has intentionally removed alert and other javascript features - more information at this link:  https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576

I will have to find another way to implement the javascript alert functionality. Thank-you all for any consideration you gave my question.